# How to get all objects of concrete class in table-per-hierarchy with hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, table-per-hierarchy

I'm developing a web application with Netbeans (Maven Web Application) using Spring MVC and Hibernate. I have an abstract class (User) with multiple concrete classes (Parent, Child, etc.). I chose for a table-per-hierarchy construction so that I have 1 tables with all the objects of these concrete classes. But I can't find a way to get all the objects of a certain concrete class. I'm getting following error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type specified for TypedQuery [domain.Parent] is incompatible with query return type [class domain.User]

Anyone who knows how I can cast these objects?

Comment: can you also post your query and the code calling it please?

Comment: I solved it using the HQL and Query-class. Well, I hope I do, I checked the class of the return type of my query and it said parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a discriminator columen in your BD, and a mapping like that:

```
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="TYPE", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
public abstract class User {
```

and:

```
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
public class Parent extends User {
```

Then you can use the attribute class in your queries. For example:

```
getSession().createCriteria(User.class).add(Restrictions.eq("class", 1))
```

or in HQL:

```
FROM User WHERE class = 1
```

Comment: I used the HQL:
String hql = "FROM User WHERE type = 'parent'";
Query query = em.createQuery(hql);
return query.getResultList();

Thanks so much !